# Viewing text files through JQuery Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tree

I would like to have a JQuery Tree display my directories and files on my system in the tree format through one of [these](http://coderbay.com/top-jquery-tree-plugins/), where if I click on a text file, the actual file will open on a new page/same page. Do the JQuery Tree plugins support that feature as I wasn't able to see an example where it did. Also for my purpose which one of the JQuery plugins would be wisest to implement?

Comment: I am using ruby on rails , so I just could open the file by using ruby with a URL, so I should be able to accomplish what after as long as I pass the URL to ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I used jsTree in a project where I bound click, right click, and double click events to each element using the usual jQuery .bind() method. You can bind an event to the nodes, get the related URL, and load the page.

I can't speak for the other plugins, but it was fairly painless to bind such events to jsTree.